# Corda - how can I model securitised loans

Tags: corda

I am creating an asset back security which is a pool of securitised loans. The abs will be fungible as it can be divided up and sold off in smaller units. This supports the basic scenario of securitisation which allows the holder of the asset to then have a balanced portion of loans for risk and return purposes.

The requirement I am struggling with is the ability to be able to verify that the underlying loans and from legitimate issuers and other characteristics without revealing the loans details. Is it possible to achieve this? I believe the only view is of the data for the abs contract but the underlying loans are not accessible. If this is possible, how would privacy be preserved on those loans?

Comment: probably this would help: https://docs.corda.net/head/tutorial-tear-offs.html

Answer (score 0):

The way I would think about this is each underlying asset (loan) is also issued on ledger by their respective borrowers and sent to the party that is creating the CDO (let's call it that for now).

Issue the CDO on ledger containing with the underlying loans as part of its state. Write the contract in such a way that it allows for the CDO to be divided up and traded.

The above is sufficient to support the first requirement.

The second requirement, to allow for verification that the underlying loans are from legitimate issues and other characteristics while hiding other characteristics can be achieved in multiple ways.

I don't think the creator of the CDO could obfuscate characteristics from the loans they receive as this would also require re-issuance of the loan by the CDO creator to break the link between the original loan issuance. This is so that walking the chain wouldn't reveal the hidden characteristics and you wouldn't be able to verify the original issuer.

The original issuance of the underlying loans could either have the hidden characteristics stored off-ledger or could make use or a trusted oracle that would only reveal them according to some defined set of rules.

Alternatively, the loan issuers could use symmetric keys to encrypt the characteristics to be kept hidden and so keep them as part of the state. The loan issuers could share the keys only when required. A hash of the entire state including the hidden characteristics could be attached to the state and could be used to achieve the same thing, with the issuer only revealing the characteristics when requested (and the hash proving they have not been changed)

This way the underlying loans are accessible from the CDO during each transaction and Verify can be run on the CDO which would reach into the attached underlying loans and run Verify on them too.